# Teacher resources on abacus for elementary school children

Tags: resource-request

What are some teacher resources on teaching elementary school children (e.g., 2<sup>nd</sup> graders) how to calculate with an abacus?

I did a search on WorldCat for related books, and surprisingly I was only able to find Ruth Merttens's *Abacus* series, which I don't think has much to do with abacuses.

Comment: Do you need books? I just searched just now, and I see what look like a lot of resources that might be good, but what I saw wasn't books. Just google, and see what you like.

Comment: @SueVanHattum If the content is good